# How to finding Intersect of array filled columns in two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

### Problem Statement

I have two corresponding DataFrames, one is employee table, one is job catalog table, one of their columns is filled with array, I want to find and intersection of two array in the `skill_set` column from two DataFrames (I've using `np.intersect1d`) and return the value to employee DataFrame for each id in employee DataFrame. 
So 1 id in employee DataFrame will be looped to find intersection of all `job_name` in job catalog DataFrame in same job rank with the current employee job rank. Final output is meant to find 5 job with highest amount of intersect (using `len` since `np.intersect1d` returns a `list`) from job DataFrames.

employee_data

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|  id|emp_name|  job_rank| skill_set|
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|   2|   c    |         1|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   2|   a    |         2|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   1|   c    |         3|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   1|   j    |         4|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   3|   k    |         5|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   1|   l    |         6|[a1,a2,a3]|
+----+--------+----------+----------+
```

job_data

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|  id|job_name|  job_rank| skill_set|
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|   2|   c    |         1|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   2|   a    |         2|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   1|   c    |         1|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   1|   b    |         4|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   3|   r    |         3|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   1|   a    |         6|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   1|   m    |         2|[a1,a2,a3]|
|   1|   g    |         4|[a1,a2,a3]|
+----+--------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Please provide your datasets as DataFrame constructors and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea how you can solve this, considering the emp data and job data are not too big.

1. Do a full join (or inner join as you need) on employee_data and job_data. So your new joined data will have len(employee_data) * len(job_data) rows and will have skills from both tables including employee details

   | emp_details | emp_skills | job_details | job_skills |
2. Operate on this table to find which of emp_skills matches with job_skills with (lambda) functions. With functions you are easily operate on array objects.
3. Select the emp details from the row